# Cannot convert type via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
class SessionHelpers
{
    public static trnUser CurrentSessionUser
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session as trnUser;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd have expected you to access something *within* the `Session` object, rather than trying to use it directly as a `trnUser`, whatever that might be.

Comment: Are you trying to cast http session to your custom object !! Or want to retrieve an object from the session ?

Comment: Hint: [`HttpContext.Current.Session`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a [`HttpSessionState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and unless you have an implicit conversion operator from a `HttpSessionState` to `trnUser`, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

error is because of the code line `HttpContext.Current.Session as trnUser` and it's pretty self explanatory which is telling that there is no relation between `HttpContext.Current.Session` and your custom composite type `trnUser` and so you just can't perform a casting operation between them.

Comment: What if there's an implicit conversion operator?

Comment: @WaiHaLee, that's a speculation/assumption made by you cause none is mentioned in OP. even there is way to bypass the compilation error and cast it by means of casting it to `object` first like `(HttpContext.Current.Session as object) as trnUser` but that won't be fruitful